# Problems with merge in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

When I merge two data.tables, the join_times in both tables are not in sync by 1 hour.

I have looked at with data.table rolling join which works but does not preserve all the rows in data.table 1 which I want

```
## convert data frames to data.tables
data_frame1_select1_DT <- data.table(data_frame1_select1)
atr_results1_DT <- data.table(atr_results1)

## create a separate date/time column in each table to join on 
data_frame1_select1_DT[, join_time:=Trade_Time_Stamp]
atr_results1_DT[, join_time:=Time]

## set keys to both data frames 
 setkey(data_frame1_select1_DT, join_time)
 setkey(atr_results1_DT, join_time)

##  merge both data.tables by the time stamp - all set to TRUE to make sure all values from both tables are saved
test_DT1 <- merge(atr_results1_DT, data_frame1_select1_DT, by = "join_time", all = TRUE, allow.cartesian=T)
test_DT1

## sort the data.table in descending order
test_DT2 <- test_DT1[order(-join_time)]
```

atr_results1_DT:

```
structure(list(atr = c(0.0501716533252073, 0.0472899885644636, 
0.0519628473409685, 0.0531110120065448), Date = structure(c(1516060800, 
1516060800, 1516060800, 1516060800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Time = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200, 
1516118400, 1516113000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
join_time = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200, 1516118400, 
1516113000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = 
c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000000002571ef0>)
```

data_frame1_select1_DT:

```
structure(list(Trade_Date = structure(c(1516060800, 1516060800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Trade_Time_Stamp = 
structure(c(1516122000, 
1516120200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
B_S = c("S", "B"), Lots_Total = c(5, 2), Avg_Price = c(63.8, 
63.79), join_time = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200), class = 
c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000000002571ef0>)
```

Results - the merge maps the  1 row according to the join_time which is 18:00.  The join_time for data_frame1_select1_DT is 17:00. The merge maps the second row according to the join_time 17:30. The join_time is data_frame1_select1_DT is 16:30. I don't understand how the join_time for data_frame1_select1_DT is ignored:

```
structure(list(join_time = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200, 
1516118400, 1516113000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
atr = c(0.0501716533252073, 0.0472899885644636, 0.0519628473409685, 
0.0531110120065448), Date = structure(c(1516060800, 1516060800, 
1516060800, 1516060800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
Time = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200, 1516118400, 1516113000
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Trade_Date = 
structure(c(1516060800, 
1516060800, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
Trade_Time_Stamp = structure(c(1516122000, 1516120200, NA, 
NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), B_S = c("S", 
"B", NA, NA), Lots_Total = c(5, 2, NA, NA), Avg_Price = c(63.8, 
63.79, NA, NA)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000002571ef0>)
```

Comment: Note the timezones. I'm guessing you're in Europe?

Comment: If 1 table is 1 hour behind, why not create a new column with time + 1 hour, and join by that?

Comment: Yes I am. So join_time needs to be set to "UTC"?